# Why is it valid to treat units as variables?

Tags: intuition, fractions, dimensional-analysis, unit-of-measure

I've always taken for granted the fact that units can be treated as variables in mathematical expressions. If you have an object that travels $10m$ in $2s$, you can simply divide the length by the time and get $5m/s$.

This works well and all, but I have started to get a bit uncomfortable with just accepting these mathematical manipulations as valid. It feels similar to treating $dy/dx$ as a fraction in calculus, it does the job most of the time, but it's not quite right.

To try and make sense of it, I went back to the definition of the division: $n/m$ means "how many times can $m$ fit in $n$". If we apply this to the velocity example above, we get: "how many times does $2s$ fit into $10m$". Not super helpful... I've tried a couple of different avenues and nothing really convinces me that treating units as variables is a valid concept.
In other words, I would love to be able to understand why dividing $10m$ by $2s$ gives us a velocity. Not only from intuition but by using rigorous mathematical notions.

Just to be clear, I am not confused about how it works. I am aware that if an object travels $10m$ in $2s$ (without any acceleration), then after a single second, 5 meters would have been traveled, thus telling us that the object is traveling at $5m/s$. What confuses me is why we can treat units as mathematical variables (Edit: Variables that are only valid under multiplication/division).

Any help and or references to works discussing these matters would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Here are some posts about this question that unfortunately have not fully answered my questions.

[Why do units (from physics) behave like numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980010/why-do-units-from-physics-behave-like-numbers)

[Why does it make sense to multiply/divide units?](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/r5bb0q/why_does_it_make_sense_to_multiplydivide_units/)

[May I treat units (e.g. joules, grams, etc.) in equations as variables?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31375/may-i-treat-units-e-g-joules-grams-etc-in-equations-as-variables)

Comment: No wonder, in general you cannot treat units as variables. For instance, try to make sense of the square root of the meter or the logarithm of the pound.

Comment: @MoisheKohan or seconds squared.. at the same time, I quite understand the OP’s concern, for example, in general we can say that if an object that has a velocity of $5$ m/s travels for $5$ s then it will pass $5$ m/s $\cdot 5$ m $= ~25$ m/s $\cdot$ s $~=25$ m.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Interesting. The third link I posted in my edit says exactly the opposite, although I am more inclined to treat them as something separate.

Comment: I can’t find it, but somewhere there’s a classic post that views units as being conversion factors from some fundamental (and arbitrarily selected) set of “god units”. So in that viewpoint when you write 7 meters, or 7 m, the “m” is literally a number that converts from the fundamental unit of distance to meters, and we are literally multiplying 7 by m. Then arithmetic with units is just arithmetic with actual numbers.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm fine with $sec^2$ or $m^{1/2}$, but things like "$5m + 2sec$" make me say you can't just treat units like variables.

Comment: @littleO I have seen this post and have included it in my edit. My problem with this explanation is that it accepts the fact that meters and seconds can be added, whereas it doesn't really make sense to do this in real life. But maybe the whole point of the argument passed right over my head.

Comment: @JonathanZ Yeah, fair enough, I guess I should say "variables under multiplication and division".

Comment: @MoyenMedium From that viewpoint, yes, technically 7 m and 30 s could be added, as they’re both just numbers. But you wouldn’t choose to add them because it wouldn’t tell you anything useful.

Comment: In a related vein, I recall an exam once in which, having been told to set basic physical constants to be dimensionless, we were asked things like our height in Coulombs.  For instance, if the speed of light is dimensionless, we have a way to convert length to time, and so on.  Good luck forming intuition out of these conversions, though.

Comment: @lulu Wouldn't any velocity be dimensionless if it is the case with the speed of light? Why say the speed of light is dimensionless instead of simply saying velocity has no dimension?

Comment: In most cases, units are just scaled version of other units. So a meter is 100 centimeters, etc.  The only units you can't really do this with is the usual temperature units, degrees and celsius. But it is unclear what it would mean to add two temperatures together - temperature is not really a scalar measure in the same way as length and time.

Comment: All basic constants are set to $1$.  That means, say, that $299792458 m = 1 s$.  So, you aren't very many seconds tall, for instance.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Even if I only consider division/multiplication, I still have a hard time digesting what it means to divide different types of units together. I understand what the final result means, but the process to get there makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: Should say, I don't consider things like $m/s$ to be division.  It's a conversion factor merely.  It's useful to write it this way as, for instance, it makes the units work out well in the usual distance = rate * time equation. But not more meaningful intrinsically than saying that there are $12$ inches in a foot.

Comment: @lulu That is precisely why I am uncomfortable with it. Despite the fact that they are not variables, we still apply the same rules that work with division/multiplication. To feel comfortable with it, I think I would need a proper proof that validates this abuse of notation.

For the same reason that there is a proof behind the abuse of notation employed by the chain rule, I feel like there should be something similar for the behavior of units.

Comment: Both [this physics.se post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98241/what-justifies-dimensional-analysis) and [this blog post by Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/) might be relevant.  They don't necessarily directly address the question of why units can sometimes be treated as *variables*, but they perhaps offer an alternative way of thinking about things that sidesteps thinking of them as variables to begin with. Perhaps.

Comment: To me, the point is that the laws must be shown to be compatible with the units.  That's where the effort comes in.  I have no idea what some one might mean by, say, grams per Coulomb, until someone tells me a law which involves both.  I don't believe the "algebraically defined" units have any meaning outside the law(s) which uses them.

Comment: Phrased differently, I consider the "speed law" to be a *definition*.  It's not the consequence of some manipulation, it defines the unit $m/s$.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the answers to the linked questions?

Comment: @Dan Most of what is being commented over there explains _how_ to use units instead of explaining _why_ it works. And as I've come to realize, it might also be because I am still unsure exactly what my question is. I have a hard time pinpointing exactly why everything makes me uneasy.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a possible formalization of units as used in the natural sciences.

It does not by any means give physical intuitions on what it means to divide units. It does say though why we can treat them like variables. The question might be ill-posed (and not just that it could be clarified further) and a tldr would simply be "why couldn't we treat them like variables". Still I hope this formalization makes you feel more at home with the concept.

As Von Neumann said,

> Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them.

With this in mind, let's begin.

---

*Intro:*

Given a commutative ring ---such as the real numbers--- you can consider a new kind of "number system" called a [polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring). Usually we call that system $\mathbb R[x]$ for $x$ the name of our variable.

As with the complex numbers where you have a distinguished element $i$ such that $i^2=-1$, here you can have a distinguished element called $m$ (for meters) and you add no restrictions as with the complex numbers, so $m^2$ doesn't reduce to anything, nor does $m^3$, etc.

In this case it would be $\mathbb R[m]$ instead.

So $m$ is just a name in this case and operations work properly as one would expect. e.g:

$$(a+bm)(x+ym) = ax + (ay+bx)m + bym^2$$

and so on.

---

*Formal variables vs usual variables:*

Polynomial rings behave just as polynomials. (In $\mathbb R$ it's the same. More generally you'd have to consider a quotient, but it's almost there.)

Most importantly you have for each real number $a$, an "evaluation morphism" $: \mathbb R[m] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that "evaluates". It's usually called $\varepsilon_a$. The $\varepsilon$ is just for evaluation: $\varepsilon$ is like a greek *e*.

So for instance $\varepsilon_2\ (1+3m+2m^2) = 1+3\cdot2+2\cdot2^2 = 15$.

In this way, the formal variable $m$ behaves like a variable in the usual sense.

---

*More than one unit:*

You can do this with as many variables as you want. You can have one for each unit.

So now we can have also $s$ for seconds. (Again, it's just a name.) And with this you can have elements like $3ms+1$ where you don't give any condition on multiplying or adding the different variable names so they just stay like that, the same way $m^2$ didn't reduce to anything before.

This number system would be written as $\mathbb R[m,s]$ or $\mathbb R[m][s]$.

Note, you can write $2m+3s$ but that doesn't reduce further. Addition of different units can be interpreted as having the two quantities separately. Formally if you forget multiplication, the sum $am+bs$ is equivalent to the vector $(a,b)$.

---

*Division:*

Finally we need a way to divide these variables. For this, we use the notion of [localization of a ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)).

Now we can do everything we want. We can have $\frac ms$ or more complicated stuff like $3\frac ms + 2\frac{m^2}s - \frac{10\frac ms}{5 s}$ and it works just like you'd expect.

And there you have it. Units are variables. (Or they behave like so, but in modern math behaving the same is being the same.)

Comment: If you care about this stuff, you'd be interested in studying abstract algebra. The book "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" by Gallian is easy to read and has everything you'd want.

Comment: This is very interesting... but how does it answer the question?

Comment: @Jme I'm sorry, I thought it did. Can you say something about why it doesn't? (Genuinely asking.) Most definitely it's not an answer about physical interpretations, but this is a math forum. Furthermore I agree all I did was "model" units formally as mathematical objects but not give reasons to why this should be the correct way to model them if this is what you're referring to. But at least to me it's definitely an answer in the sense that it makes me feel more comfortable with the concept of units.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, ignore me. The question is a bit vague, this probably is the best answer you can give. Thanks :)

Comment: "It does not by any means give physical intuitions on what it means to divide units. It does say though why we can treat them like variables." I think this is the closest thing I can get to an answer for now. We define units, and then we attribute physical meanings to them. I am still uncomfortable with the idea of accepting $m*m =m^2$ as an area, or $m/s$ as a velocity (even though they are defined as such), but this may be because I still don't know what I'm uncomfortable with. Stepping back and reflecting on what I am trying to understand might be my best course of action for now.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because it works well, and tells you what you can and can't do. For example, if you multiplied $7$ and $2m$, intuitively that means a length that is 7 times longer than 2 meters. If you do it algebraically, treating m as a variable, you get $7(2m)=14m$, which is correct. However, if you did $7m*2m$, you *don't* want a 1 dimensional value. You want a 2d value, in meters squared. If you do the algebra, $7m(2m)=14m^2$, which is, again, correct. As to the $m\overs$ intuition, I like to think of it as "how many meters can you move in one second?".

Comment: Although I do understand that $7m*2m$ will have $m^2$ as units, this still doesn't prove its validity. I would love a way to confirm beyond a shadow of a doubt that it is valid. Saying "You don't want a 1-dimensional value" is unfortunately not enough to convince me that multiplying meters together will yield an area. What is so special about multiplication that it can transform length into another type of unit? I may be focusing my efforts in the wrong direction right now. It feels a bit like trying to understand why the speed of light is what it is... It just is.

Comment: @MoyenMedium I think you're touching upon the problem in your last sentence... before one can prove anything about "units" you would need what "units" are axiomatically, and in any framework that does that, it would likely simply include an axiom along the lines of "when you multiply two objects with the "unit" of length, the resulting object has a unit of length squared" so maybe you should first try to figure out what exactly it is that you are asking

Comment: @Carlyle This question has proven to be way more difficult to answer than I originally anticipated. I may put this to rest for now and come back to it once I have the proper mathematical background to answer it.

Comment: @MoyenMedium I don't think this question is difficult to answer, I think its difficult to formulate in a meaningful way, and once that has been done, the answer will likely be "by definition"

Comment: @MoyenMedium I mean... Yeah. The definition of area is that it's in 1 dimensional units squared. And if you multiply 1 dimensional units, you can think of that as setting them as the side lengths of a rectangle with the result as the area. It just is. Sorry I couldn't help you out :/

Comment: My best guess is just that variables worked. They worked for the definitions provided, because it doesn't really make sense to add seconds and meters together, does it? But saying speed is the amount of length you can traverse in some amount of time, well, that fits with division.